# c++ classes member functions

Tags: c++

With the following code, where the member functions are declared in the class, it prompts the user to enter various inputs like hours and pay.

```
cout << endl << "Now please input info #1" << endl;
Info p1;
cout << endl << "Now please input info #2" << endl;
Info p2;
p2.combineinfo(p1);  /**< combines the info, like hours, pay, ect.  */
printinfo(pnew);  /**< prints out the combined paycheck information  */
```

The information is put into `p1` and `p2` accurately because I can confirm with a `cout`. However, `p2.combineinfo(p1)` prompts again for a set of information inputs. I don't want this, I just need it to pass to this function to get combined and then be printed out with `printinfo();`.

```
Info Info::combineInfo(Info p1)
{
Info p2;
Info pnew;
pnew.name = p1.name;
pnew.hours = p1.hours + p2.hours;
pnew.total = p1.total + p2.total;
return pnew;
}
```

Updated Info:

```
Info::Info()
{
string dummy;
cout << "question here"<<endl;
getline(cin, a);
cout <<"question here"<<endl;
cin >> b;
getline(cin, dummy);
cout <<"question here"<<endl;
cin >> c;
getline(cin, dummy);
cout << "quesiton here"<< endl;
initializeDate(start);
cout << "question here "<< endl;
initializeDate(finish);
}
```

Comment: In case you can't tell from the syntax highlighting here, `new` is a keyword.

Comment: edited, thanks -- they aren't my variables in my code so it's alright.

Comment: It seems as if some details must have been lost in translation, because the use of the local, uninitialized "p2" variable inside your combineInfo function seems nonsensical, there's no clarity as to the relationship between your Info class and the I/O statements in your first code sample, and there's clearly no way that combineInfo function is doing any I/O unless the I/O is happening in an Info constructor (since these Info objects are getting created and copied all over the place).

Comment: show us your constructor

Comment: @JBentley I really appreciate your feedback but it's just for beginner purposes (self teaching) so 1 step at a time.

Comment: I combined all my comments into an answer to reduce clutter.

Comment: @JBentley Very helpful, thanks. I'm getting an error that `pnew` is not declared in the main scope. What do I do about that? It's in reference to printinfo(pnew);.

Comment: @user2163672 I have edited my answer to show the corrected code (near the top of the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I ended up typing a lot of comments, I've combined it into an answer:

As per the other answers, your issue is that you are calling `Info`'s constructors in your `combineInfo` function, and you are prompting the user in the constructors. It's usually a bad idea to use `std::cin` inside a constructor - What if you (or your code's users) decide to use the code in a situation where `std::cin` is inappropriate (e.g. when you later decide to upgrade to a GUI)? What if you want to construct the object with pre-determined data? Or in a unit test?

In fact your own code provides just such an example: you've defined `Info` in a way that the only way it can be constructed is by asking for info from the user. However, you have *two* ways that you actually want to construct the object - (1) by prompting for info from the user, and (2) by combining info which *already exists* inside two other `Info` objects (`p1` and `p2`).

The better solution is to have the constructor receive the data via parameters - `Info::Info(string name, int hours, int total)`, obtain the info from the user outside the class (when appropriate), and pass it in to the constructor.

Alternatively, if you're determined to keep the `cin` code inside the constructor, then do not use a `compareInfo()` function - make a *second* constructor which takes two `Info` objects as parameters, and place your code there:

```
Info::Info(Info p1, Info p2)
{
    name = p1.name;
    hours = p1.hours + p2.hours;
    total = p1.total + p2.total;
}
```

Then do your combining like this:

```
Info pnew(p1, p2);
```

EDIT: you've commented that have a criterion you must stick to, namely that the combining must happen inside a `Info Info::combineInfo(Info)` function. This is awkward because your constructor prompts for information, and you must construct a temporary `Info` object inside your member function:

```
Info Info::combineInfo(Info p1)
{
Info pnew; // Temporary Info object
pnew.name = p1.name;
pnew.hours = p1.hours + hours;
pnew.total = p1.total + total;
return pnew;
}
```

You have three solutions that I can think of, none one of them particularly attractive (and I am surprised that a teacher would impose this requirement on you):

(1) Provide a constructor which does not prompt for info. However it must have a different signature to the one which does request info, because you cannot define a default constructor twice:

```
Info::Info()
{
   // Prompt user.
}

Info::Info(int dummyValue)
{
   // Do nothing.
}
```

Then when you create your `pnew` object, call the second constructor: `Info pnew(0);`.

(2) Do not provide a default constructor at all, instead create one which you inform whether or not to prompt:

```
Info::Info(bool prompt)
{
    if (prompt)
    {
        // Construct object by prompting user.
    }
    // No need to do an else, simply do nothing if !prompt
}
```

This has the disadvantage that you will always have to supply a parameter to construct Info objects:

```
Info p1; // Error, no default constructor
Info p1(true); // Construct by prompting
Info pnew(false); // Construct without prompting
```

(3) Do not create a temporary `pnew` at all, just modify `p1` and return that. This is poor style, and only works because you have passed `p1` by value (therefore you are not modifying the original `p1`):

```
Info Info::combineInfo(Info p1)
{
// No need to do anything with name since it's p1's name you want anyway
p1.hours += hours;
p1.total += total;
return p1;
}
```

---

### Other comments:

You also have a couple of bugs in your code as it stands:

```
cout << endl << "Now please input info #1" << endl;
Info p1;
cout << endl << "Now please input info #2" << endl;
Info p2;
p2.combineinfo(p1); // You are not saving the return value.
printinfo(pnew);  // pnew does not exist, see above.
```

Change the code to this:

```
cout << endl << "Now please input info #1" << endl;
Info p1;
cout << endl << "Now please input info #2" << endl;
Info p2;
Info pnew = p2.combineinfo(p1); // Now you are saving the result.
printinfo(pnew);  // pnew now exists.
```

The second bug is as follows:

```
Info Info::combineInfo(Info p1)
{
Info p2; // You're creating a new p2 object, this is
         // NOT the p2 you called the function on.
Info pnew;
pnew.name = p1.name;
pnew.hours = p1.hours + p2.hours; // Wrong p2
pnew.total = p1.total + p2.total; // Wrong p2
return pnew;
}
```

This only *seems* to work correctly for you, because of the constructor issue - you're being prompted to enter the info for `combineInfo`'s `p2`, so it ends up being the same as the `p2` you actually intended to use (assuming you entered the same data again), and it seems to combine them correctly. Do this instead:

```
Info Info::combineInfo(Info p1)
{
// Info p2; // Delete this line
// your intended p2 is passed to the function as the implicit parameter.
Info pnew;
pnew.name = p1.name;
pnew.hours = p1.hours + hours; // hours refers to implicit parameter
pnew.total = p1.total + total; // total refers to implicit parameter
return pnew;
}
```

`hours` and `total` in this case are shorthand for `this.hours` and `this.total`.

Another thing to consider for future reference, is to overload the `+` operator instead of writing a combine function:

```
Info Info::operator+(Info p1)
{
Info pnew;
pnew.name = p1.name;
pnew.hours = p1.hours + hours;
pnew.total = p1.total + total;
return pnew;
}
```

Now instead of:

```
Info pnew = p2.combineInfo(p1);
```

You can write:

```
Info pnew = p1 + p2;
```

Finally, consider passing by reference instead of by value - for non-trivial objects it's usually faster for the function to dereference the address instead of making a new copy of it:

```
Info Info::combineInfo(const Info& p1); // p1 passed by reference
                                        // const replicates the behaviour
                                        // of pass by value whereby
                                        // you cannot accidentally modify
                                        // the original object.
```

EDIT: But don't do this if you use solution 3 above, otherwise you will modify the original `p1` which is probably not desireable to you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think it needs to be pnew.printinfo();. I may have lead you to think that because it's in my original question.

Comment: That's fine, just change `printinfo(pnew)` to `pnew.printinfo()` and add a `void printinfo()` function to your `Info` class, and do all your printing in there.

Comment: Also, im still being prompted for a third set of info after inputting Information #2.

Comment: @user2163672 It's the constructor issue again. When you create `pnew`, it gets constructed, and prompts you for the info (for the `pnew` object). This is a fundamental problem with your code - it goes completely against the grain of what a constructor *is*. A constructor constructs objects from the data you supply it. I.e. object's creator tells the constructor what data to use for the creation. You are warping it into a constructor which *itself* asks for the data from a source unrelated to either the object *or* the object's creator (`cin`).

Comment: You've effectively found your own reason to add to my list of examples of why you shouldn't put `cin` in a constructor - you've discovered that you actually want to construct `Info` objects in *two* ways - one, by prompting the user for the info, and two, by creating an `Info` object which is the combination of two existing objects. For the latter, it makes no sense to ask the user for info because you *already have* the info in `p1` and `p1`. The solution is to take the info-requesting logic outside the class.

Comment: JBentley: OK, I understand. I'm supposed to create two constructors - one that takes in all the arguments to initialize the fields and one that takes in no arguments and reads from the user. I'm stumped because it doesn't seem like both functionality can exist at same time. I need to get the `pnew` so that it doesn't prompt the user for more info but I also need to be able to do `Info p1` in main and prompt for inputs.

Comment: @user2163672 Yes, exactly, two constructors. I've edited my answer again with this solution.

Comment: JBentley:  OK, so I want to combine two sets of information. I believe I only need one parameter to do that though because I'm combining the parameter info with the info that combininfo lives within...I need to use member function `Info combineinfo(Info p1)` for the sake of this program.

Comment: @user2163672 Well this makes things awkward. I'll edit in a workaround in a minute.

Comment: JBentley: Yeah, I've been working on this the past week. I really appreciate your help -- learning from your explanation is better than just seeing the code. thx.

Comment: @user2163672 Ok, I provided you with three alternative solutions. Read from the word "EDIT" onwards in my answer.

Comment: @user2163672 Out of the three, I'd probably go with (3) since it doesn't require you to change much else about the way you're doing things.

Comment: JBentley: This works perfect, now I have to digest all your wonderful help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't show it but you are probably asking for the input in the Info constructor. Something like:

```
Info::Info()
{
   cout << "Enter name: ";
   cin >> name;
   cout << "Enter hours: ";
   cin >> hours;
   cout << "Enter total: ";
   cin >> total;
}
```

So in combineInfo you create two objects of class Info, so the constructors run and it asks for input for each one. Just don't ask for the values in the constructor. Add another method AskForInput to ask for the values and don't call it from the constructor.

Comment: Carlos: Yes, that's correct, I posted my actual info construction in the question. Could you please show me example of what you mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing you're reading in input froms stdin inside your constructor for Info (could you post this code?). thus, when you create p2 and pnew again, it's calling that very same code.

i suggest you have separate code for initializing a variable with stdin, instead of your constructor. otherwise, there's not much you can do here about it being called!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have decided have the default constructor for `Info` read in the value. Then in the method `combineInfo` you again have a couple of constructors which must do the same.

You can avoid the problem by having a method after construction that prompts for the data. If you show your constructor code that might help.

Having said that, most likely the method ought to read:

```
void Info::combineInfo(const Info& p1)
{
    name = p1.name; // Why not keep p2.name?
    hours += p1.hours;
    total += p1.total;
}
```

and then call:

```
printInfo(p2);
```

Comment: Keith: For this project I'm not supposed to make it a void function and I can't use `const`. The member function must be Info combineinfo(info p1)